# How to display properties of array data with class-validator and swagger nestjs

Tags: swagger, nestjs, class-validator

I have the following dto

```
export class ProductDTO {
  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => ProductsAttributesDTO)
  attributes?: ProductsAttributesDTO[];
}
```

the attributes of my other dto `ProductsAttributesDTO`, are not displayed in the swagger, because my `attributes?: ProductsAttributesDTO[];` it is an array, if remove type array `attributes?:ProductsAttributesDTO` it is displayed correctly, how can i make this display

my prodcutsAttributesDTO

```
export class ProductsAttributesDTO {
  @ApiProperty({ example: 'e09eeeb6-b894-432a-8818-84e42ed12d1c' })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  attributeId: string;

  @ApiProperty({ example: 'Panasonic' })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  value: string;
}
```

how swagger displays

```
"attributes": [
    "string"
  ],
```

how do i need

```
"attribute": [
    {
      "attributeId": "e09eeeb6-b894-432a-8818-84e42ed12d1c",
      "value": "Panasonic"
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the Array in the @type:

```
@Type(() => ProductsAttributesDTO)
@Type(() => ProductsAttributesDTO[])
```

Comment: "I think" should be comment not answer